# Selenium locator : Invalid element state

Tags: javascript, selenium

There is a website, where I can do automated login. The environment is Javascript, Selenium (but this may not matter).
I need to run the same code for an another website. I checked the locator at the new website, slightly modified the locator, but when I try to login automatically, I get error message : "Invalid element state". My locator seems to be good, because when I change it (I make it wrong), then I get error message "element wasn't found".

So with locator  `$("//*[@name='username'] ")`  error message is "Invalid element state"
With locator `$("//*[@name='doesnotexist'] ")` error message is "element wasn't found"

So the first locator seems to be good (because error message is not related to element that was not found), but there is still error message.

This is the "whole code" around it :

```
get inputUsername() 
{ 
   return $("//*[@name='username'] ");
}

login (username) {
    this.inputUsername.setValue(username);
}
```

Can you please help me, why I get the "Invalid element state" error message ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: The element is not present in the DOM that loads in the second case. Most probably in a frame. If that is the case then you have to switch to the frame first.

Comment: Thank you Ahmed, however I think, that the locator, where "Invalid element state" is the test result should be used.I mean, that the "doesnotexist" is not on the page at all, therefore I get message "element wasn't found". Then I change the "doesnotexist" text in the locator to "username", so :  return $("//*[@name='doesnotexist'] "); to  return $("//*[@name='username'] ");, and the error message changes to "Invalid element state". So the 'username' is good, but I still get the "Invalid element state" message. This is the problem.

Comment: If you could share the page link or the page DOM then it would be easier to understand.

Comment: Thank you Ahmed, now my code works. The problem was that I should have used "addValue", this is the right command. "setValue" does not do, what I wanted (write value to an Edit box), though setValue does not cause compilation error. This was a tricky bug.